# Creating quarterly report from excel/csv file in latex

Tags: overleaf, report, csv

I am trying to create a quarterly report in latex from a database in excel/csv.
for the report I only need certain attributes and their corresponding values.
So far Ive managed to create a suitable table with the attributes in question.
the problem is, that all the values are plotted in the cell next to the first attribute and not corresponding to their specific attribute.

Here is my code:
[image]

here is a snapshot of the plotted table:
[image]

and here is my test.csv:
[image]

I am very new to this and would greatly appreciate your help!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. Please don't post images of code/data. They are of no help to anyone. Instead put the code the and sample CVS data into your question directly. You can format code by selecting it and clicking the `{}` icon.

Comment: Welcome. // Please produce a reduced version of both your .tex and .csv, which we can copy an compile. E.g. just a header and 2 lines with dummy content will suffice. If necessary, you may want to follow this checklist: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10137/245790 . Thank you